# Small custom markers on android google maps v2

Tags: android

I am using android google maps v2, with custom markers.
The problem is that they work fine on *mdpi* screens, while on *hdpi* or *xhdpi* screens they appear **too small**.

My markers come from assets (or from a server, via HTTP), they are designed as 160 dpi bitmaps, therefore just after decoding them I set their density attribute, as in the following simplified code sample:

```
InputStream inputStream = mAssetManager.open(filename); // Asset case
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); // HTTP case
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
icon.setDensity(160);
```

When I put them on the map, I do the following:

```
BitmapDescriptor descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon);
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
    .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
    .icon(descriptor));
```

I expected, as in v1 map library, that the library would take care of scaling them according to their density, compared to screen density. But this does not seem to be happening. Is this a limitation of v2 map library? Shall I explicitly resize my icons before putting them on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I have adopted the solution that follows.

Define a variable to keep the display density:

```
protected int mDpi = 0;
```

In the onCreate method, initialize it:

```
mDpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
```

Adjust icon size according to display density, by using this method:

```
protected Bitmap adjustImage(Bitmap image) {
    int dpi = image.getDensity();
    if (dpi == mDpi)
        return image;
    else {
        int width = (image.getWidth() * mDpi + dpi / 2) / dpi;
        int height = (image.getHeight() * mDpi + dpi / 2) / dpi;
        Bitmap adjustedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
        adjustedImage.setDensity(mDpi);
        return adjustedImage;
    }
}
```

The purpose of adding dpi / 2 to the dividend is to calculate a rounded quotient, instead of a truncated one.

Hope it helps!